# Enable https on Node-Express App on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have a node Express app running on an AWS EC2 Instance. I am able to run the server and connect to the express app using **http:**//ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-242.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

But when I use **`https`** instead of **`http`**, it doesn't work, despite having port 443 open on my instance.

Could some one please suggest how I could enable **https** on my express app.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var httpsRedirect = require('express-https-redirect');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));
app.get('/health-check', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// *** HERE I am setting my App to listen on port 443

//app.listen(8080);
app.listen(8443);

module.exports = app;
```

Here are the rules on my EC2 Instance, where the port 443 is open for all traffic.

[image]

I enabled I forwarding from port 443 to 8443 on my AWS EC2 Linux Instance:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Opened the Linux firewall to allow connections on port 443:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Where are you configuring the SSL certificate? I don't see any SSL configuration at all. Setting up SSL is much more involved than just changing the port to 443.

Comment: I agree, I have created an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS that directs traffic (https) to the above EC2 instance. The ELB has an SSL configured.

Comment: Then most of your question doesn't make sense. You should be handling SSL traffic on the load balancer, and fowarding all traffic from the load balancer to HTTP on port 80 of your NodeJS server. You shouldn't be configuring NodeJS for port 443 at all, and you shouldn't be trying to test HTTPS by directly loading the URL of your EC2 server at all, because that obviously won't work.

Comment: @MarkB from your suggestion, I've configured my load balancer to port 80 on NodeJS server and now https calls to my ELB are being served. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: @Minsky I didn't say that you did, so why are you asking me that?

Comment: @Minsky don't use this question as an example, if it was working they wouldn't have needed to ask the question. Yes it's possible to stand up a simple express.js app and point a load balancer to it without doing most of what is being attempted in this question.

Comment: @Minsky you're really tacking too many of your own questions into the comments of this question. Express.js is a framework you use for building web apps, not a single stand-alone file that you run. You should work through the **Getting Started** section here http://expressjs.com/

Comment: @MarkB asked new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100212/open-ec2-aws-express-server

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will get you there for sure. But the quick path on AWS is to use an application load balancer which takes care of setting up and renewing your certificates: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy but require some time for understanding how it usually works. 
This should be great place to start: https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/

In few words:

1. stay your express app as is
2. generate certificates
3. install and configure reverse proxy which will handle https. Nginx is great choice.